# How to get json from icecast into react component?

Tags: json, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, cors, fetch

I've been trying to figure out why this json isn't working to my advantage. According to jsonlint its not valid json. How could I convert this to valid json? I've tried using fetch and xhr. I was fixing the cors issue and now I'm stumped. I've searched but not sure I have found anything like this.

my react component method:

```
  fetchData() {

      var url = 'http://192.168.1.10:8000/status-json.xsl'
      var self = this;
      fetch(url, {
          'mode': 'no-cors'
      })
          .then(function(response) {
              return response.json()
          }).then(function(json) {
              console.log('parsed json', json)
          }).
      catch (function(ex) {
          console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      })
      xhr({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
          },
      }, function(err, data) {
          var body = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(body)
          self.setState({
              data: body,
          });
      });
  },
```

My icecast json.

```
{
icestats: {
admin: "",
host: "",
location: "",
server_id: "Icecast 2.4.1",
server_start: "Tue, 28 Jun 2016 14:41:06 -0500",
server_start_iso8601: "2016-06-28T14:41:06-0500",
source: [
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 3,
listeners: 0,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-2nd-1",
server_description: "RADIO-2nd-1",
server_name: "RADIO-2nd-1",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://192.168.1.176:81",
stream_start: "Wed, 19 Oct 2016 17:06:24 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-19T17:06:24-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=75",
bitrate: 75,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 0,
listeners: 0,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-2nd-2",
server_description: "RADIO-2nd-2",
server_name: "RADIO-2nd-2",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://192.168.1.176:82",
stream_start: "Wed, 12 Oct 2016 19:24:26 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-12T19:24:26-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 7,
listeners: 4,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-5th-1",
server_description: "RADIO-5th-1",
server_name: "RADIO-5th-1",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://192.168.1.83",
stream_start: "Wed, 19 Oct 2016 23:43:45 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-19T23:43:45-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 0,
listeners: 0,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIOBK-4th-1",
server_description: "RADIOBK-4th-1",
server_name: "RADIOBK-4th-1",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://192.168.1.10",
stream_start: "Wed, 02 Nov 2016 14:00:42 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-11-02T14:00:42-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 2,
listeners: 0,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-1st-1",
server_description: "RADIO-1st-1",
server_name: "RADIO-1st-1",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://156.127.4.72",
stream_start: "Tue, 18 Oct 2016 08:06:39 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-18T08:06:39-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 6,
listeners: 1,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-2nd-1",
server_description: "RADIO-2nd-1",
server_name: "RADIO-2nd-1",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://156.127.4.62",
stream_start: "Tue, 18 Oct 2016 09:56:00 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-18T09:56:00-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 3,
listeners: 0,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-3rd-1",
server_description: "RADIO-3rd-1",
server_name: "RADIO-3rd-1",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://156.127.82.80",
stream_start: "Wed, 12 Oct 2016 19:24:26 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-12T19:24:26-0500",
dummy: null
},
{
audio_info: "bitrate=39",
bitrate: 39,
genre: "court",
listener_peak: 0,
listeners: 0,
listenurl: "http://192.168.1.10/RADIO-3rd-2",
server_description: "RADIO-3rd-2",
server_name: "RADIO-3rd-2",
server_type: "audio/mpeg",
server_url: "http://156.127.82.81",
stream_start: "Wed, 12 Oct 2016 19:24:26 -0500",
stream_start_iso8601: "2016-10-12T19:24:26-0500",
dummy: null
}
]
}
}
```

Error in Browser console:

```
index.js:216 OPTIONS http://192.168.1.10:8000/status-json.xsl net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE_createXHR @ index.js:216createXHR @ index.js:50fetchData @ _template.jsx:139proxiedMethod @ createPrototypeProxy.js:44exports_render @ _template.jsx:433tryRender @ index.js:34proxiedMethod @ createPrototypeProxy.js:44(anonymous function) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:793measureLifeCyclePerf @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:74_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:792_renderValidatedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:819performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:361mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:47performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:47performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:47performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:47performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:47mountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:105perform @ Transaction.js:138batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:127perform @ Transaction.js:138batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:63batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:98_renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js:321_renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js:402render @ ReactMount.js:423(anonymous function) @ web-entry.js:79module.exports @ .gatsby-context.js:15(anonymous function) @ web-entry.js:69loadConfig @ web-entry.js:35(anonymous function) @ web-entry.js:68(anonymous function) @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:2396__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:554fn @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:85(anonymous function) @ multi_main:2(anonymous function) @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:584__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:554(anonymous function) @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:577(anonymous function) @ bundle.js?t=1478278055741:580
VM7812:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval [as callback] (webpack:///./_template.jsx?:147:23)
    at cbOnce (webpack:///../~/xhr/index.js?:62:21)
    at loadFunc (webpack:///../~/xhr/index.js?:138:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.readystatechange (webpack:///../~/xhr/index.js?:68:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that JSON keys like `icestats` should be quoted: `"icestats": {...`

Try to replace your `status-json.xsl` with this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:import href="xml2json.xslt"/>
<xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="application/json"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- override imported transform variable to enable output -->
<xsl:variable name="output">true</xsl:variable>

<!-- hide certain nodes from all sources -->
<xsl:template match="icestats/source/max_listeners" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/source/public" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/source/source_ip" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/source/slow_listeners" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/source/*[contains(name(), 'total_bytes')]" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/source/user_agent" >
    <!-- user_agent is most of the time the last node in a mount, 
         if we just delete it, then we will malform the output, 
         so special handling applies. -->
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*"></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">"dummy":null}</xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>

<!-- hide certain global nodes -->
<xsl:template match="icestats/sources" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/clients" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/stats" />
<xsl:template match="icestats/listeners" />
<xsl:template match="node()[contains(name(), 'connections')]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also add this file `xml2json.xslt` to Icecast web directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="application/json"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!--default to no output-->
  <xsl:variable name="output">false</xsl:variable>

  <!--constant-->
  <xsl:variable name="d">0123456789</xsl:variable>

  <!-- ignore document text -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node() or following-sibling::node()]"/>

  <!-- string -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Main template for escaping strings; used by above template and for object-properties 
       Responsibilities: placed quotes around string, and chain up to next filter, escape-bs-string -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-bs-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Escape the backslash (\) before everything else. -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-bs-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'\')">
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'\'),'\\')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-bs-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,'\')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Escape the double quote ("). -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-quot-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'&quot;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'&quot;'),'\&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,'&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace tab, line feed and/or carriage return by its matching escape code. Can't escape backslash
       or double quote here, because they don't replace characters (&#x0; becomes \t), but they prefix 
       characters (\ becomes \\). Besides, backslash should be seperate anyway, because it should be 
       processed first. This function can't do that. -->
  <xsl:template name="encode-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- tab -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'&#x9;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'&#x9;'),'\t',substring-after($s,'&#x9;'))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- line feed -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'&#xA;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'&#xA;'),'\n',substring-after($s,'&#xA;'))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- carriage return -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'&#xD;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'&#xD;'),'\r',substring-after($s,'&#xD;'))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$s"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- number (no support for javascript mantissa) -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(string(number())='NaN' or
                       (starts-with(.,'0' ) and . != '0'))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- boolean, case-insensitive -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[translate(.,'TRUE','true')='true']">true</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()[translate(.,'FALSE','false')='false']">false</xsl:template>

  <!-- objects and arrays -->
  <xsl:template match="*" name="base">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- complete array -->
      <xsl:when test="(count(../*[name(current())=name()])=count(../*)) and count(../*[name(current())=name()])&gt;1">
        <xsl:variable name="el" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[name()=$el])">
          <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="../*[name()=$el]">
            <xsl:if test="position()!=1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="not(child::node())">
                <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- partial array -->
      <xsl:when test="count(../*[name(current())=name()])&gt;1">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">{</xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="el" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[name()=$el])">
          <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$el"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>:[</xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="../*[name()=$el]">
            <xsl:if test="position()!=1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="not(child::node())">
                <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">}</xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- object -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">{</xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="name()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <!-- check type of node -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- null nodes -->
            <xsl:when test="count(child::node())=0">null</xsl:when>
            <!-- other nodes -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <!-- end of type check -->
          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">}</xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- convert root element to an anonymous container -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="$output='true'">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And please check that your JSON URL (`http://192.168.1.10:8000/status-json.xsl`) is working, try to open it in a browser for example, because this error:

`http://192.168.1.10:8000/status-json.xsl net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE_createXHR`

means that response was empty.

Here is a working example from one of my internet radios, it's not React (jQuery) but it should work the same.

Pay attention to:

1. You don't have to parse response `JSON.parse(data)` because returned data is in JSON format.
2. My Icecast instance is configured to respond with this header:

> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
> ```

that allows us to bypass CORS restriction. Add this lines to your Icecast config file:

> ```
> <icecast>
>     <http-headers>
>         <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
>         <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since" />
>         <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, OPTIONS, HEAD" />
>     </http-headers>
> ...
> ```

And here is my snippet (it outputs current track title):

```js
jQuery.get("http://stream.indiecore.fm:8000/status-json.xsl", {}, function(response){
  console.log("Now playing: ", response.icestats.source[0]['title']);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I replaced status-json2.xsl in /etc/icecast2/web and added xml2json.xslt to the web folder. I restarted the server and the json output is the same.

Comment: I'm starting to think the issue is related to the "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". I can confirm that the file is there and can view in the browser.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Using Jquery does solve it. This is a working solution. I prefer to use react fetch to try and grab this data. So I will work from here. Thank you.